# JPA @Query annotation does not seem to be using paramter

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring Boot application using JPA/Hibernate as entity management/modeling. I have the following user class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long Id;

    private String name;
    //more fields, getters and setters below
}
```

I want users of my application to be able to search for users by name. So in my repository interface, I have:

```
  public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
       @Query(value = "SELECT u from User u WHERE lower(u.name) LIKE lower(:name)")
       List<User> findByNameLike(@Param(value="name") String nmae);
  }
```

Then in my UserController, I have:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users/")
public @ResponseBody List<User> search(@RequestParam String name) {
    return this.userRepository.findByNameLike(name);
}
```

This always returns an empty list. I know the name parameter is coming in correctly. 
Moreover, I do know that it is recognizing the `@Query` annotation, because if I change the query to something like

```
SELECT u FROM User u
```

it will return me all users. Or if I change it to

```
SELECT u from User u WHERE u.name = '%Bob%'
```

and remove the parameter from the method, it will return all users whose name is Bob. I've tried other variations of the query, such as

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE lower(u.name) LIKE CONCAT('%', lower(:name), '%')
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = :name (even a simple equals doesn't work)
```

and so on and so forth. Every source I look at whose syntax I copy seems to say I'm writing the query right, so I think something else must be going on.
I've also tried letting Spring generate the query for me, using

```
public List<User> findByNameLike(String name);
public List<User> findByNameContaining(String name);
```

which also don't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated here!

Comment: My guess is that the name is not actually what you think it is. Try with a hardcoded name value. Print the numeric value of each character of the name to make sure there is no hidden space character.

Comment: That was it. I was doing something like:GET localhost:8080/users?name='Dan', but then it was including the quotes in the search string. So I removed the quotes. Thanks so much. Can't believe I spent a few hours on this.

Comment: Always challenge your assumptions. The problem is almost always located between the keyboard and the chair ;-). Been there, done that.

Comment: Turn on 'trace' level debugging for the hibernate packages (like in log4j) so you can get a trace of what the actual SQL is that's getting run, along with parameters.

Comment: @DanV you should delete this question, since you got the answer, and the question will probably not help anybody in the future. I'll vote to close for typo in the meantime.